I want to switch the CPU of one of my laptops with another laptop's cpu
I got a nice (but cheap) laptop - Nimo 15.6 FHD - for my birthday. I also have a laptop - HP ENVY 13 - a friend gave to me, but it was broken, and I didn't have the money to fix it.
I checked and the CPU of the laptop my friend gave me was much better than the one that the Nimo came with - 3.4 GHz Pentium vs 8th gen i7. If possible, I would like to swap the CPU from the ENVY to the Nimo, but I'm not sure if I can. I don't know if I can add anything else from the ENVY to my Nimo, but if there is I would also like to know. I have a link for the Nimo laptop below. (I couldn't find a link to the ENVY)

https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0DN1JHGLP


There are a few questions on this site already dealing with upgrading laptop CPUs. Please read these. It is likely your questions are already answered: https://superuser.com/search?q=upgrade+laptop+cpu

he Pentium N100 and 8th gen i7 used two different sockets..  Given the processors are not even in the same generation and do not have the same number of pins there is zero chance those the processor you have identified is compatible with your system.

@Ramhound - just to be an ass***e: 8th gen i7 used at least 4 different sockets across just mobile versions... But that's obviously completely beside the absolutely correct point.
